# Javascript - .length returning 0

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

So I'm working on this problem and for the life of me can't figure out why .length is not coming up with the correct value. It only returns 0, which I assume means it's not waiting for the function to complete.

I've tried having a counter and an if statement waiting for the length of the array to be equal before returning the sortPerms.length. But it evaluates to true in the beginning.

If I just return the array "sortPerms" it returns the correct amount of values in the array.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Here is code:

```
var regex =  /(.)\1+/g;
var sortPerms = [];
function permAlone (str) {
    var perms = [], combos = [], letterOne = str[0];
    if (str.length === 1) { 
        perms.push(str);
        return perms;
    }

    str = str.substring(1,str.length);
    combos = permAlone(str);

    for (var i = 0; i < combos.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < combos[i].length + 1; j++) {
           perms.push(combineCombos(combos[i], letterOne, j));
        }
    }
    sortPerms = perms.filter(function(string){
        return !string.match(regex);
    });
    return sortPerms.length;
}


function combineCombos(combo, lettersIn, i) {
    var begin = combo.substring(0,i);
    var end = combo.substring(i,combo.length);
    return begin + lettersIn + end;
}
```

Comment: What do you want the code to do?

Comment: This is a fairly complex algorithm, and the variable names aren't very descriptive of what you're trying to accomplish. It's difficult to know what's wrong when we aren't given the expected output and an explanation of how this should get the output.

Comment: That is probably not why `.length` is returning `0`. In JavaScript `.length` is a static property of a string. If `string.length` returns `0` then you are looking at an empty string.

Comment: `combos = permAlone(str);` gives the `permAlone()` function a recursive element. However, the `permAlone()` function is `return`ing a number value (the length of `sortPerms` in `return sortPerms.length`), which is *not* the string you're expecting when you pass that return value into `combos`. `combos` is then *not* holding the expected (required) value(s), and your algo fails at that point, and each iteration thereafter.

Comment: How does the function call of permAlone look like? What does the abbreviation perm stand for? Please have a look into the youtube videos from Robert C. Martin and Michael Feathers about Clean Code and Refactoring. You could make your function perm alone more readable by using the refactoring technique "Extract method". By using short methods that have speaking names the code could yell at us what it is doing :-) But at present it is hard to decipher what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the function has a return value that sometimes is an array (`return perms;`) and in other cases a number (`return sortPerms.length`). Yet when you call the function recursively (`combos = permAlone(str)`), you clearly expect an array (`combos.length`).

So the final return statement should read:

```
return sortPerms;
```

And now the following call:

```
permAlone("abc");
```

returns:

```
["abc","bac","bca","acb","cab","cba"]
```

... which seems what you are after.

If you need the length of the array, then don't code that in the `return` statement, but do it in your call:

```
console.log(permAlone("abc").length); // 6
```

Comment: Did this answer your question? Could you leave a comment?